# R: Shiny and Ggplot2 show different plot with same code

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Have data for everyday of dicember 2014. want to plot a barchart according to the selection of dates:

Original data:

```
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), .Label = c("2014-12-01", 
"2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", 
"2014-12-07", "2014-12-08", "2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", 
"2014-12-12", "2014-12-13", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", "2014-12-19", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", "2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", "2014-12-26", 
"2014-12-27", "2014-12-28", "2014-12-29", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31"
), class = "factor"), sessions = c(197L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 566L, 1L, 27L, 159L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 129L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
1L, 28L, 1L, 7L, 386L, 1L, 146L, 1L, 89L, 41L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 182L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 524L, 4L, 26L, 1L, 152L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
10L, 142L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 
375L, 3L, 2L, 147L, 1L, 101L, 29L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 224L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 141L, 
4L, 632L, 2L, 2L, 32L, 1L, 138L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 139L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 36L, 1L, 
537L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 174L, 1L, 106L, 39L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 689L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 35L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 20L, 465L, 1L, 3269L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 32L, 6L, 2L, 
293L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 433L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 37L, 10L, 88L, 6L, 1808L, 5L, 4L, 451L, 5L, 219L, 
112L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 264L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 516L, 1L, 948L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 1L, 133L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 168L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 98L, 1L, 548L, 1L, 1L, 177L, 97L, 17L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 235L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 
19L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 396L, 1209L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
41L, 1L, 125L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 121L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 75L, 
5L, 632L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 178L, 1L, 67L, 33L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 12L, 3L, 194L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 296L, 1L, 1L, 979L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 
109L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 118L, 
1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 6L, 53L, 3L, 
584L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 172L, 2L, 100L, 27L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 11L, 3L, 202L, 6L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 292L, 
719L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 29L, 106L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 3L, 139L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 20L, 53L, 3L, 
530L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 172L, 113L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
891L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1312L, 
1L, 1L, 1168L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 39L, 133L, 3L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 297L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 25L, 182L, 1L, 776L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 260L, 2L, 115L, 52L, 
14L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 
2L, 731L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 294L, 
1L, 1135L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 126L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 355L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 5L, 67L, 1L, 2L, 926L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 208L, 1L, 1L, 136L, 44L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 198L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 205L, 568L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 94L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 157L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 28L, 3L, 444L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 118L, 2L, 75L, 27L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 166L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 203L, 644L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 
4L, 75L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 155L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 446L, 3L, 1L, 99L, 86L, 
27L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 159L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 174L, 733L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
100L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 38L, 7L, 502L, 2L, 1L, 86L, 6L, 
83L, 24L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 321L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 13L, 191L, 1L, 5L, 1417L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 
150L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 218L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 4L, 45L, 1L, 
3L, 879L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 207L, 2L, 115L, 44L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 171L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 178L, 614L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 20L, 1L, 94L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 433L, 1L, 3L, 23L, 94L, 79L, 25L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 160L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 568L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 15L, 5L, 86L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 118L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 530L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 72L, 34L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
326L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1271L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 161L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 195L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 20L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 1050L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 19L, 1L, 196L, 134L, 52L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 120L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 371L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 74L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 382L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 54L, 17L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 168L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 374L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 10L, 6L, 85L, 1L, 1L, 
16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 393L, 3L, 17L, 53L, 75L, 22L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 136L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
488L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 71L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 126L, 
5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 445L, 
1L, 1L, 90L, 1L, 77L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
248L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 981L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 134L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 194L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 
850L, 1L, 1L, 155L, 1L, 117L, 43L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 124L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 373L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 63L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 125L, 7L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 287L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 54L, 1L, 49L, 19L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
289L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 61L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 241L, 1L, 5L, 42L, 1L, 51L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 98L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 251L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 47L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 73L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
214L, 2L, 1L, 40L, 41L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 103L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 270L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 60L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 73L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 219L, 1L, 55L, 60L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 168L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 404L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 99L, 
3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 115L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 362L, 1L, 2L, 
64L, 2L, 88L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 104L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 343L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 10L, 64L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 106L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 286L, 1L, 2L, 43L, 2L, 56L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 140L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 479L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 20L, 87L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 118L, 5L, 
1L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 389L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 1L, 75L, 
13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
341L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 101L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 85L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 278L, 10L, 67L, 2L, 54L, 
15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 315L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 13L, 1L, 59L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 90L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 235L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 53L, 72L, 
18L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 68L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 241L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 37L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 197L, 47L, 39L, 19L, 1L), Fuentes = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Adwords", "Campañas", 
"Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"sessions", "Fuentes"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1724L))
```

My data after the summarise function:

```
    Fuentes     sessions
1   Adwords       71
2   Campa�as      280
3   Directo       11610
4   Email         437
5   Referencias   13143
6   SEO           39837
7   Social Media  5981
```

**Howcome my shiny code does not print right my plot?**

1) when used within Shiny, the label appears like blured:

[image]

do a summarise before plotting (see code below):

server.R file:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
require(scales)




Visitas_Por_Fuente <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\Movistar-App-2\\Visitas_Por_Fuente_Dic.csv")
labelsF = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Adwords")
Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)




shinyServer(


function(input, output) {



output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

  # Filter the data based on user selection month     
  date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


  VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labelsF)

  VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
                  summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))



  ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15"),
                      labels = labelsF,
                      values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                 "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#A082F8", "#F072A2"))

})
```

})

[image]

2) Then i use the same code, but not within shiny, just ggplot2 code:

```
ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15"),
                    labels = labelsF,
                    values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                               "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#A082F8", "#F072A2"))
```

And get what i need:

[image]

I also tried, using a reactive function (as recommended in comments), but got:

```
Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive
```

Googled that and found:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771691/many-error-signs-when-running-ggplot-in-render-plot-shiny-in-general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd9UL.png)

But now,prints a blank sheet:

[image]

This is my code with the reactive function:

```
  function(input, output) {

    dataSeq <- reactive({
                 date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")
    })


    VisitasData <- reactive({
      VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% dataSeq  & Fuentes %in% labelsF)

      VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
        summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))
    })




    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({


      # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
      ggplot(ggplot(selectedData(VisitasData), aes(factor(VisitasData$Fuentes), VisitasData$sessions,
                                                   fill = Fuentes)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
        geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
        scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15"),
                          labels = labelsF,
                          values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                     "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#A082F8", "#F072A2"))

    })


  })
```

Comment: try doing your filtering not in in `renderPlot` but in a reactive function before it. You can assign this to an object and then call it in the `renderPlot`.

Comment: @jalapic, tried that but first got: Error : `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive`. After searching, i change my code, but now nothin prints... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want those numbers that showed up in your first call

```
    Fuentes     sessions
1   Adwords       71
2   Campa�as      280
3   Directo       11610
4   Email         437
5   Referencias   13143
6   SEO           39837
7   Social Media  5981
```

You just made a little mistake here:

```
VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
        summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))
```

You made a new dataframe, but you didn't assign it to anything. What you want is:

```
VisitasData <- VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
        summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))
```

Then you don't need to do a reactive thing, just used the code you did when you first posted it above.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
require(scales)


Visitas_Por_Fuente <- read.csv("D:\\RCoursera\\Movistar-App-2\\Visitas_Por_Fuente_Dic.csv")
labelsF = c("Directo", "Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media", "Campañas", "Adwords")
Visitas_Por_Fuente$date <- as.Date(Visitas_Por_Fuente$date)


shinyServer(

  function(input, output) {

    output$VisitasFuente <- renderPlot({

      # Filter the data based on user selection month     
      date_seq <- seq(input$dates[1], input$dates[2], by = "day")


      VisitasData <- filter(Visitas_Por_Fuente, date %in% date_seq  & Fuentes %in% labelsF)

      VisitasData <- VisitasData %>% group_by(Fuentes) %>%
        summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))

      # Bar graph using ggplot2 library 
      ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
        geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
        scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15"),
                          labels = labelsF,
                          values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                     "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#A082F8", "#F072A2"))

    })

  })
```

Is this what you intended?